# SVG padding only applies when at least 2 sides are specified

Tags: css, svg

Why does an SVG require at least 2 areas to be padded for any padding to apply?

For example giving an svg `padding-top: 50px` will do nothing. But giving it `padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 1px` will cause the padding to be applied.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4aMfZ/

Comment: padding-top works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/4Lu8T/

Comment: Interesting... that doesn't show any padding on my browser (chrome Version 35.0.1916.114). Which browser are you in?

Comment: Version 34.0.1847.131 on OSX

Comment: Wow, yea this totally only seems to be a Chrome thing im assuming unique to my version. How do I file a bug to the chrome team...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear to me that `padding` should apply to SVG elements.  Padding is designed for the box model layout, which SVG doesn't use or care about.  Except, that is, for it's position within the HTML document.  If you want space around the outside of an SVG, use `margin` instead.

Comment: using padding worked in chrome, but not safari for me. I switched to using margin and both worked.